# ChartJS - Line chart - Additional padding top/right to add additional lines

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I created a chart using Chart.js, but would like add additional space after the last x and y line to make it look like "it could continue".
I've looked at multiple attributes from the documentation and other answers on SO but couldn't find a solution.

**What i have**
[image]

**What i want to achieve**
(Note the extra lines on the top/right edges)
[image]

**JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/zncbv9o6/

I also tried to use

```
layout: {
    padding: {
        right: 20
    }
}
```

which, however, only adds space around the chart and not from the inside to add these lines.

Comment: are you aware of adding  `offset:true` to your axis? i tried it in jsfiddle but the problem it add padding to both sides of axis.

Comment: @AlanOmar Yes, I've seen that one too and just like you mentioned, both sides are affected :/